# Login window not showing for Swagger using Flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, swagger, flasgger

I have a REST API set up with Flask that has some API documentation.

The documentation is in the code itself, and I am using Flasgger to run the API documentation interface.

The issue is that upon trying to access the API, with the URL `https://<server_address>/apidocs/index.html`, there is no log in box that is showing up. I merely get the result `Authentication required` in my browser window.

[Browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXXQv.png)

I am expecting a window like this:

[Login window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9TvI.png)

Which I do not get on the remote server. I can log in on localhost perfectly, but not on my remote server.

For some reason the remote server is not giving me that login window. I have tried using both HTTP and HTTPS, because there was mention somewhere that the protocol mattered as well.

Library versions:

- flask-swagger==0.2.14
- flasgger==0.9.5
- pytest-flask==0.15.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your code...?

Comment: Basically using exactly this: https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger/blob/master/examples/basic_auth.py